# Open sets in quotient topology and $T_0,T_1,T_2$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to do this exercise but I can't do it because I can't understand who are the open sets in the quotient topology.

Let $X = [0,2] \cup [4,6] \subset (\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$. We define this equivalence relation on $X$.

[image]

$X/\sim$ is T0,T1,T2?

Proof.:

We identify the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[4,5]$, so $[0]=[4]$ and $[1]=[5]$.

Now I try to understand who are the open sets:

$A=(a,b)$, with $[1]=[5] \in (a,b)$. So $\pi^{-1}(a,b)=(a,1] \cup [5,b)$... and this is NOT open in the susbspace topology...right? I can't obtain $(a,1]=X \cap A'$, with $A' \in \tau_e$

Can someone help me understanding other open sets and how to find them?

Thanks

Comment: I am not really familiar with this, but can it help if you define a suitable quotient map? I would go for $\pi:X\to\mathbb R^2$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\langle x,0\rangle$ if $0\leq x\leq 2$, $x\mapsto\langle x-4,0\rangle$ if $4\leq x\leq 5$ and $x\mapsto\langle1,t-5\rangle$ otherwise. You can easily visualize $X$ and its image, and start wondering which preimages of $\pi$ are open sets.

Comment: In the definition of the equivalence relation, how is the semicolon to be interpeted?  As 'and', 'or', something else?

Comment: it's a definition by cases... In the text there was a brace

Comment: @feddy.  The definition is badly stated.  Do you mean '(p or q) and r' or do you mean 'p or (q and r)' in two cases of the definition?

Comment: I edited the text... Now it should be clear

Comment: Well one problem with your proof is that $[1]\neq[5]$.  This is also where the separation axioms may fail to hold.

Comment: Yes, thank you ... I made a terrbile mistake! How can I move to find open sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "point" in the quotient is just an equivalence class of $\sim$.

All equivalence classes are either a singeleton like $\{5\}$ or a doubleton like $\{0,4\}$. A set of classes is closed if their union is closed in the original space (which corresponds to the inverse image under the quotient map $q$). Ditto for open.
So all sets of the form $\{[x]\}$ are closed in $X/\sim$, and so the quotient is $T_1$ and a fortiori $T_0$. In general $T_1$ of the quotient comes down to the simple question of "are all classes closed?" if so, then yes, if not, then no.

For Hausdorffness I'd start by looking at the classes $[1] = \{1\} \neq [5] = \{5\}$ (a weird "glue point"..they "should be" equivalent from their left neighbours point of view but are not).

If $U$ and $V$ are open sets containing $[1]$ and $[5]$ resp. we know that $q^{-1}[U]$ is an open neighbourhood of $1$ and $q^{-1}[V]$ is an open neighbourhood of $5$. This means that there is some $r>0$ such that $1-r \in q^{-1}[U]$ and $5-r \in q^{-1}[V]$ But then $q(1-r) = q(5-r)= \{1-r, 5-r\}$ is a common point of $U$ and $V$ and $U$ and $V$ are not disjoint.
So $X/\sim$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: It's almost clear now. I have still a doubt: you say: "If $U$  and $V$ are open sets containing $[1]$ and $[5]$ resp...". How do you know that those open sets exists? I mean, how are the open sets in $X// \sim$?

Comment: @feddy I assume they exist to get a contradiction. Then I just apply continuity of $q$.

Comment: Ok, a last question : how can I see that " all sets of the form {[x]} are closed in $X/∼$?" using the quotient map

Comment: @feddy $q^{-1}[\{[x]\}] = [x] \subseteq X$ and all $[x]$ are finite thus closed. Hence, $\{[x]\}$ is closed by definition.of the quotient topology.